# Is there a better term for subdomains of SE?

Tags: discussion, terminology

It can get tedious using the term subdomain to keep referring to math.stackexchange.com, tex.stackexchange.com etc.  Is there a better term to use?

Comment: "Site" is the term used (on stackexchange.com).

Comment: You can refer to them as `math.SE`, `tex.SE`, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could generally refer to `sites.SE`, or "sites of the Stack Exchange Network" in full.

Comment: To be clear, "sites" is what I was looking for. I didn't consider it because I thought of all of SE as one site, but I see that it's a flexible enough word and appears to be common usage to call each *.SE a different site.

Answer (score 8):

Instead of saying `You could ask on Math.SE`, try using a little bit of ownership in the pitch and say `You could ask our Math community on Stack Exchange` instead. That opens up a little more conversation as to what both mean, and the actual sub domain becomes kind of incidental.

Technically speaking, they *are* sub domains, so I'm not sure if there's any better word than that.

Comment: The Trilogy aren't subdomains in the DNS sense, so using this term to refer to SO/SU/SF is calling for a pedant pointing this out. “Site” or “community” are better in this respect.

Comment: @Gilles They are _still_ Stack Exchange sites, Note that Gaming has its own official domain now. In a network of 70+, that's going to happen from time to time. The question was asking about making the sub domain less confusing. It might not hurt to have the trilogy sites accessible via a `.stackexchange.com` domain though, just for uniformity.

Comment: @TimPost: I'm sorry, I don't understand your answer. "Ownership in the pitch"? Why would I only ask math.SE for a term that applies to *.SE? Both? I do understand your final statement...though it proposes no alternative.

Comment: Thanks @Gilles for "community". I like that better than "sites" because sites would refer more to the difference between SE and SO?

Comment: @Travis Tim proposed *community*, not me (though I agree that it is a good word). It looks like you misread his answer.

Comment: @Gilles Ah, so he did. (Since he used the term instead of presenting it, it slipped by me in all the rest of the English and I had to do a find to see it.) My apologies Tim. (Though I still don't understand "ownership in the pitch" etc.)

Comment: @Gilles I get SE/SO, but what are SU/SF?

Comment: @Travis SU = [su], SF = [sf]